# TypeScript 3.0 React defaultProps support not working

Tags: typescript

Trying to use this feature which has been available since TypeScript 3.0: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#support-for-defaultprops-in-jsx

```
export interface Props {
  name: string;
}

export class Greet extends React.Component<Props> {
  static defaultProps = { name: 'world'};
  render() {
      const { name } = this.props;
      return <div>Hello ${name.toUpperCase()}!</div>;
  }
}

// Type-checks! No type assertions needed!
let el = <Greet />
```

According to the documentation above, this should pass type checking. This is the exact code from the documentation, but I get this type checking error on the line `let el = <Greet />`

> [ts] Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Readonly'.   Property
>   'name' is missing in type '{}'. [2322]

This is what I'd expect if the feature didn't exist. Tried with TypeScript 3.1.6 and 3.2.4.

Are people successfully using this feature? Is there a compiler directive or something I need to enable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading to the newer version of `@types/react`, it works with 16.4.11.

Comment: This is not what I'm asking. I'm asking why the compiler fails type checking for the code snippet above. The code above is correct, and as I said it's actually copied directly from the TypeScript documentation.

Comment: You are missing required name property of the component.

Comment: Please go read the reference in the TypeScript documentation I linked to. The entire point of this question is that TypeScript 3.0 is supposed to support `defaultProps` and not require including props that are members of `defaultProps`.

Comment: Your error is because you are missing name property in the <Greet /> component, try doing it like this

**let el = <Greet name={} />**

Comment: You just repeated your prior comment again. I appreciate you are trying to help, but this is incorrect and is not helpful.

You clearly haven't read the reference I linked above. TypeScript 3.0 has a feature that makes this valid code. This code is copied directly from the TypeScript documentation. There is no answer to this question that involves changing the code. I'm not asking you how to change the code, I'm asking why it doesn't compile without type errors as the documentation states.

Comment: This is because, before TypeScript 3.0, there was support for defaultProps, but you can still make use of it, just mark props that have defaults as optional with ?

Comment: Sigh. I really think we have a communication problem. I'm not going to respond any more. Thank you for trying to help but this answer is incorrect and I'm not able to help you understand what I'm asking.

Comment: What version @types/react you are using?

Comment: Now, I think you're on to something. I am using an old version of prop types. So maybe I just need to upgrade?

Comment: Try upgrading to the newer version, it works with 16.4.11.

Comment: Got it to work - props also needed to be updated. If you update this answer to this, I'll accept it!